# Understanding sed command syntax and sed commands

Tags: bash, sed

Could someone explain what this `sed` command does here?

```
sed 's!^M$!!;s!\-!!g;s!\.!!g;s!\(..\)!\1:!g;s!:$!!'
```

It seems replacing/deleting some characters... But I couldn't figure it out... It's really complicated (I mean all of those `s`  `;`  `/`  `g`  `M`  `^` . and other characters)

thanx
regards

Comment: I think I've seen this in a different question of yours: something is off with your `I` characters when typing: they are all `ı`, which is kind of hard to read.

Comment: He's Turkish, using the ı character.

Comment: yeah we are using ı in here..and yeah it can be made hard to read..sorry for that.. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split it up into a series of substitutions:

```
s!^M$!!
s!\-!!g
s!\.!!g
s!\(..\)!\1:!g
s!:$!!
```

Each one is using `!` as the delimiter, so the patterns are `s!match!replacement!`. The `g` on the end means that some of them are global, so will happen as many times as possible rather than only once on each line.

`^` matches the start of the line and `$` matches the end, so the first one removes any `M`s that are found on a line by themselves.

The next two remove all `.` and `-` that are found. The `.` needs a slash before it so that it only matches a literal `.` rather than matching *any character*. The `-` doesn't need a slash before it but it doesn't do any harm either.

The fourth one adds a `:` after every 2 characters, using a capture group and back reference.

Hopefully you can work out what the last one does, based on my explanation of the first one!

Comment: thank you so much again..5th substitution is removing any : character from line i guess..but its a bit confusing..i mean script is adding : with 4th subtitution but removing them with 5th substitution..its really weird.. Second issue is that 5th substitution seems didnt use ^ and $ whereas 1st substitution is using them.. So what is the differences between 1st substitutiom and 5th substitution? Thanx again best regards

Comment: Not quite - it only matches any `:` at the end of the line `$`.

Comment: Ahh..sorry..i understood now. Thanx again